# How we can change or set properties of html elements from UI like MS word elements

Tags: javascript, css, html, web, drag-and-drop

I am new in web development , I am working on DnD (drag & drop) , I make a small code which can drag and drop only one element any where on page . But Now I am want set their properties from UI for example see that link : https://www.draw.io/

Anyone can help me please . Thanks !

code is following which I did :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<title></title>   
<style>    
#dragme { 
    position:  absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0; /* set these so Chrome doesn't return 'auto' from getComputedStyle */
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.66); 
    border: 2px  solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    border-radius: 4px; padding: 8px;
}

</style>    
<body>

<div style="height:700px;width:100%;border:2px solid green;background-color:#60CEFB;"> 
<input type="button" draggable="true" id="dragme" style="color:#fff;width70px;height:50px;border:2px solid white;background-color:black;box-shadow:1px 1px 1px 1px grey;" value="Go India" name="button" />
<script>
function drag_start(event) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null);
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain",
    (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"),10) - event.clientX) + ',' + (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top"),10) - event.clientY));
} 
function drag_over(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    return false; 
} 
function drop(event) { 
    var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');
    var dm = document.getElementById('dragme');
    dm.style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0],10)) + 'px';
    dm.style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1],10)) + 'px';
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
} 
var dm = document.getElementById('dragme'); 
dm.addEventListener('dragstart',drag_start,false); 
document.body.addEventListener('dragover',drag_over,false); 
document.body.addEventListener('drop',drop,false); 
</script>   
</div>    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code for what you have tried so far?

Comment: @PraveenPuglia Now you can see my implemented code .